# EasyCAP with VLC Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, video, vlc, mplayer, easycap

I got an EasyCAP DC60+ video capture and want to use it to capture gameplays from a nintendo Wii.

I have managed to install the drivers for the capturer (i think) and i can capture video on Mplayer by using the following code:

By doing so, a Mplayer window pops-up with the output from the wii, [image: like this], but no sound comes out.

In many tutorial to set up VLC with this i have seen that i need to go to media > Open Capture device and change Capture Mode to "video 4 linux2" and then choose the EasyCAP DC60 from the Video Device Name blank and an Audio Divace Name (dont know what to do here). However, i dont have such options, [image: This is what i have on Capture Mode], [image: Video Device Name] and [image: audio device name].

I am totally stuck, please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Capture mode: Video camera
2. Video device: `/dev/video0` (1st camera)
3. Audio device: `hw:0,0` (if you would like to record mic, otherwise leave blank)
4. Click `Play`
5. Menu View → Check *Advanced Controls* to record on the main control bar.
6. Press *Record* the red dot button to start/stop recording. (Records are stored by default in your Videos folder)